# Stack overflow exception thrown for no reason when trying to print all balanced binary strings with length n

Tags: java, recursion, binary, concatenation, stack-overflow

These two methods throw a stack overflow exception when they use each other. The first is to produce all binary strings using recursion, and the second is to check if it is balanced. Do you know why? When I run them independently, they run normally. str will be entered as an empty string at the beginning, and n is the required size of the string.

```
public static void printEqualBinaries(String str, int n) {
        if (str.length() == n && isBalanced(str,n)) {
            System.out.println(str);
            return;
        }
        String k1 = str + "1";
        printEqualBinaries(k1, n);
        String k2 = str + "0";
        printEqualBinaries(k2, n);
    }

    public static boolean isBalanced(String str, int n) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            int index = n / 2 - 1;
            int sumLeft = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++) {
                sumLeft += Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(str.charAt(i)));
            }
            int sumRight = 0;
            for (int i = index + 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
                sumRight += Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(str.charAt(i)));
            }
            if (sumLeft == sumRight) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            int index = n / 2;
            int sumLeft = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                sumLeft += Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(str.charAt(i)));
            }
            int sumRight = 0;
            for (int i = index + 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
                sumRight += Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(str.charAt(i)));
            }
            if (sumLeft == sumRight) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printEqualBinaries("", 3);
    }
```

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you want this to do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Each and every call of this method `printEqualBinaries(str, n);` with input params `(str.lenght() != n )` becomes an infinite loop because condition `(str.length() == n )` always evaluates to false;

If you add 'stop' conditions for both k1 and k2, you will get 4 binary strings in your case and for e.g. printEqualBinaries("", 13); 1848 results like (HashMap output):

> {1110001010110=0001110101001, 1101000100101=0010111011010, 1110001101001=0001110010110, 1001010101010=0110101010101, 1101000111000=0010111000111, 1010110011101=0101001100010, 1001010010110=0110101101001, etc. }

Of course under assumption that this is what you mean by balanced.